# Callback hell in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

I am experiencing a "callback hell" situation in Node.js.

Basically what I want is:

Read data from a static json file (local) --> query MongoDB to get two records from two separate collections --> compare the returned data -> add the result after compare into result object --> go to next step in the loop --> repeat.

Please review the code and let me know where is the problem.

```
 jsonfile.readFile(file, function(err, staticData) {
if(err){
  console.log("Error while loading Tower Details from Static Data " + err);
}
else{
  var staticD = staticData.Teams;
  var l = staticData.Teams.length;
 // console.log('*******************Getting Tower Level Data from Static File*******************');
  //console.log('*******************Tower Name received is ******************* ' + staticData.Tower);
      if(counter == l){
        console.log('Inside the couneter loop');
       res.json(testObject);
      }
  for ( var i = 0 ; i<l; i++){
   var trackName = staticD[i].name
   console.log('Counter--------->>>>' + counter);
    //console.log("Team name " + staticD[i].name);
        ++counter;
    for (var j = 0 ; j<staticD[i].applications.length;j++){
     //var RObj;
     //var AObj;
      //console.log("Application Name " + staticD[i].applications[j]);
      var applicationName = staticD[i].applications[j];
      var test = new Object();
      test.data =  [];
      var resultSet;

     var response = reference.find({'appname' : applicationName , 'track' : trackName }).sort({'_id': -1});
     var promise = response.exec();
     var alertT = alert.find({'appname' : applicationName , 'track' : trackName }).sort({'_id': -1}).limit(1);
     var promise1 = alertT.exec();

        promise.then(function allRefRecords (recordAlerts){
         if(recordAlerts.length >0){
          //console.log('Ref Length' + recordAlerts.length);
        recordAlerts.forEach(function refRecord(R){
          testObject.data.testInfra.push(R);
          //console.log('testObject' + testObject.data.testInfra);
          });
    }

          });

        promise1.then(function allAlertsRecords (alerts){
          if(alerts.length > 0){
        alerts.forEach(function refRecord(a){
        // console.log('a' + a)
         testObject.data.testCustom.push(a);
          //console.log('testObject' + testObject.data.testCustom);
         // res.json(testObject);

       });
      }           
          })
        .then(function(){
           resultSet = compareData(testObject.data.testCustom,testObject.data.testInfra);
           test.data.push(resultSet);
          })
        .then(function(){
          res.json(test);
        });
    }

  }

}

});

});
```

Comment: I will suggest you to use `async` in your code, instead of using for loop.

Comment: I have tried the promises in the code, however i am getting variable results. sometime i am getting 2 records and sometimes 3.

Answer (score 3):

> Don't nest functions, give them names and place them at the top level
>   of your program.   Use function hoisting to your advantage to move
>   functions 'below the fold'.   Handle every single error in every one
>   of your callbacks and use a linter like standard to help you with
>   this.   Create reusable functions and place them in a module to reduce
>   the cognitive load required to understand your code.   Splitting your
>   code into small pieces like this also helps you handle errors, write
>   tests, forces you to create a stable and documented public API for
>   your code, and helps with refactoring.

Source : http://callbackhell.com/

It is possible to avoid callback hell with ASYNC, with PROMISES, with DESIGNS, and many other ways... 
But 99% of time, design is the finest (imho) and you don't need other things.

Some links :
[How to Elegantly Solve the Callback Hell](https://www.terlici.com/2015/10/28/solving-node-callback-hell-asyncjs.html)
[Avoiding Callback Hell in Node.js](http://stackabuse.com/avoiding-callback-hell-in-node-js/)

Remember that callback hell is not a fatality ;)

Comment: i have tried promises in the code and now I am getting the results. However, the number of records in the results is random. Meaning sometime i am getting 2 records and sometime 3 and this is the response for same request.  All i want is : get one record from reference collection , then get one from alert collection then compare the two object fetched in previous step and return the result back. I am adding code snippets as well.

Comment: Code Snippet#1 response = reference.find({'appname' : applicationName , 'track' : trackName }).sort({'_id': -1});
      var promise;
      promise = response.exec();
      var alertT;
      alertT = alert.find({'appname' : applicationName , 'track' : trackName }).sort({'_id': -1}).limit(1);
      var promise1;
      promise1 = alertT.exec();

Comment: Code Snippet#2 : promise.then(function allRefRecords (recordAlerts){
         if(recordAlerts.length == 1){
          recordAlerts.forEach(function refRecord(R){
          testObject.data.testInfra.push(R);
          });
          }
         });

Comment: Code Snippet#3 :  promise1.then(function allAlertsRecords (alerts){
          itemProcessed++;
          if(alerts.length == 1){
         alerts.forEach(function refRecord(a){
         testObject.data.testCustom.push(a);
          resultSet = compareData(testObject.data.testCustom,testObject.data.testInfra);
         returnObject.data.push(resultSet);
           }); 
         }

         if(itemProcessed == parseInt(total)){
     
          res.json(returnObject);
         }
                 
          });

Comment: Add your codes that you have tried in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Some tips to prevent a further appearance of **Callback Hell** you can browse next libraries:

- **Async.js:** you can execute functions in series without nesting them.
- **Bluebird:** asynchronous logic will be more manageable with mapping and enqueueing.
- **Q:** reveals the concept of promise to manage the nested calls effortlessly.